# Retrieving R object attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, htmlwidgets, onrender

I have a bivariate dataset with 100 observations. I used hexagon binning and ended up with 26 hexagon bins. In order to save the rows of the 100 observations that are in each of the 26 hexagon bins, I used the `base::attr` function in R. In the code below, this is done at:

```
attr(hexdf, "cID") <- h@cID
```

I am trying to create an interactive R `Plotly` object of the hexagon binning so that if a user were to click on a given hexagon bin, they would obtain the rows of the 100 observations that were grouped into that bin. I have part of this goal completed. My MWE is below:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(GGally)
library(hexbin)
library(htmlwidgets)

set.seed(1)
bindata <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:100), A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100))
bindata$ID <- as.character(bindata$ID)

x = bindata[,c("A")]
y = bindata[,c("B")]
h <- hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=5, shape=1, IDs=TRUE)
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
attr(hexdf, "cID") <- h@cID
pS <- ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID)) + geom_hex(stat="identity")

ggPS <- ggplotly(pS)

myLength <- length(ggPS[["x"]][["data"]])
for (i in 1:myLength){
  item =ggPS[["x"]][["data"]][[i]]$text[1]
  if (!is.null(item))
    if (!startsWith(item, "co")){
      ggPS[["x"]][["data"]][[i]]$hoverinfo <- "none"
    }
}

ggPS %>% onRender("
          function(el, x, data) {
            //console.log(el)
            //console.log(x)
            //console.log(data)

            myGraph = document.getElementById(el.id);
            el.on('plotly_click', function(e) {

            cN = e.points[0].curveNumber
            split1 = (x.data[cN].text).split(' ')
            hexID = (x.data[cN].text).split(' ')[2]
            counts = split1[1].split('<')[0]
            console.log(hexID)
            console.log(counts)

           })}
           ", data = pS$data)
```

When I run this code and open it in the Web Browser, I obtain an interactive plot like below (green box is not in plot; it's superimposed for explanatory purposes):

[image]

If I click on the hexagon inside the green box, the correct `hexID` of 40 and `counts` of 3 are printed to the console. At this point, I would like to obtain the 3 rows of the original data frame that were put into that hexagon bin.

I know how to do this in R outside of the `onRender()` function of the `htmlwidgets` package by using the `base::attr` function. For instance, I can do the following:

```
hexID=40
obsns <- which(attr(pS$data, "cID")==hexID)
dat <- bindata[obsns,]
```

And receive the following correct 3 data points that were put into that bin I clicked on:

```
     ID         A        B
47 ID47 0.3645820 2.087167
66 ID66 0.1887923 2.206102
71 ID71 0.4755095 2.307978
```

I am working with much larger datasets than in this MWE. For that reason, my intention of using the `base:attr` function was to prevent ever larger data frame floating around. However, I am unsure how to translate the functionality of the `base::attr` function so that I can access the appropriate data point rows that occur in a clicked hexagon bin in the `onRender()` JavaScript code. I did include the `pS$data` object into the `onRender()` JavaScript code, but am still stuck.

Any advice would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a column which for each row has the ID of the hexbin it belongs to in your bindata:

```
bindata$hex <- h@cID
```

You can then pass it to the `onRender` function and filter rows when the users clicks on a hexagon:

```
ggPS %>% onRender("
                  function(el, x, data) {
                  myGraph = document.getElementById(el.id);
                  el.on('plotly_click', function(e) {

                  cN = e.points[0].curveNumber
                  split1 = (x.data[cN].text).split(' ')
                  hexID = (x.data[cN].text).split(' ')[2]
                  counts = split1[1].split('<')[0]

                  var selected_rows = [];

                  data.forEach(function(row){
                    if(row.hex==hexID) selected_rows.push(row);
                  });
                  console.log(selected_rows);

                  })}
                  ", data = bindata)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I realize that I lacked the foresight and oversimplified my MWE so that there is a solution (as you showed) that does not require base::attr() to be used. The solution can still be helpful for me and others. I just wrote a better MWE that I hope shows more clearly why I feel stuck still with the base::attr() and why I don't think the solution here will work for that case. I posted that in a Part 2 version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460061/retrieving-r-object-attributes-in-javascript-part-2). Thank you.

Comment: I've thing the same strategy would work for part 2, I've posted a solution that hopefully works on your full example.